# imputing values in a column basis values and condition in other columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am working on a large database with close to 1mn rows. It is a time series data with electricity consumption by shops during the day. The objective is to identify the spikes and use some form of imputation to correct for the spikes. Shops, Time and Electricity are original columns and then I created Spikes as a column that captures spikes above 2 stddev.

Objective:

Now I need to create a column, say, Smooth, where I use some form of imputation to correct for the spikes. We could used average of the previous and the next row, KNN or stochastic regression imputation. Suggestions are welcome but please share code as well as I am raw.

One important point to be noted is that while imputing, we have to ignore opening and closing working hours, so say 7-9HRS and 16-18HRS since these are opening and closing hours of business and spikes are expected. But during the day and in non-business working hours all spikes should be addressed. Below is the example of db I have and the Smooth column is what we need.

```
df = {'Shops': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B'], 
'Time': ['5AM', '6AM', '7AM', '8AM', '9AM', '10AM', '11AM', '12PM', '1PM', '2PM', '3PM', '4PM', '5PM', '6PM', '7PM', '8PM', '9PM', '10PM'],
'Electricity': ['0.70', '1.00', '0.50', '0.80', '1.00', '1.10', '1.50', '1.30', '1.00', '1.20', '1.00', '0.60', '0.40', '0.20', '0.20', '0.30', '0.60', '0.50'], 
'Spikes': ['Nan','1.00','Nan','Nan','Nan','Nan','1.5','Nan','Nan','Nan','Nan','Nan','Nan','Nan','Nan','Nan','0.5','Nan'],
'Smooth': ['0.70', '"Impute"', '0.50', '0.80(Ignore the spike as it is between opening hours)', '1.00', '1.10', '"Impute"', '1.30', '1.00', '1.20', '1.00', '0.60', '0.40 (Ignore the fall as it is between closing hours)', '0.20', '0.20', '0.30', '"Impute
"', '0.50']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['Shops', 'Time', 'Electricity', 'Spikes', 'Smooth'])
```

df

Answer (score 0):

Just a hand waving suggestion here. I guess, if you have had a basic introduction to numerical analysis then you might have learnt about interpolation. Once you find out the time stamps where there are spikes (as per your definition of 2 std. dev.), you may run a function at those points that take into account points to the left and right of the spiky point and tries to fit a smooth curve.
Simplest being

```
def smoothen(array, spike_index ,type='mid_pt_avg'):
    if type == 'mid_pt_avg'
        left  = array[spike_index-1]
        right = array[spike_index+1]
        array[spike_index] = (left+right)/2.0
    elif type == 'quadratic_interpolation':
         pass

    elif type == 'bezier_interpolation':
         pass

    elif type == 'KNN ':
         pass

    else:
         # whatever is your last option
```

Comment: Thanks @Sowmya for your revert. Maybe I am too naive to get this but when I tried to implement it, it is not working showing error. Can we use the above example column names to show how this will work on your code assuming we stop at KNN. Also how are we factoring in the working hours filter which will ignore the spikes in certain timebands in the above code? Thanks again!

Comment: What I provided was a simple pseudo code and it is not suppose to work. However, do we agree that the part of filtering should be done separately from smothering? I don't want to look at how you filtered (in fact I do want to look) when my job is to smooth the wrinkly curve given the point of wrinkle. That's it.